# Disintegration of many particles Landau (Mechanics 3rd Ed page $43$)

Tags: classical-mechanics

On page $41$ Landau states that the total momentum in the C system is $0$.

On page $43$ for the disintegration of many particles, Landau states: In the C system... every resulting particle (of a given kind) has the same energy...

Why is this?

I understand why the statement is true if the momentum of a primary particle is $0$.

Comment: There are many books by Landau, and in several editions. Which book, which edition, and what is the context.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention which book. It's Mechanics (3rd edition). Many primary particles disintegrating into two particles. In the C system, where the total momentum is zero, all particles of a given kind have the same energy. I don't understand why this is correct.